# Passing Boolean as Arg to a command

Tags: macros, arguments

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

%booleandeclaration
\newboolean{istest}
\setboolean{istest}{false}

%Set boolean in if
% \newcommand{\activate}[1]{%
% \ifnum#1>0{\setboolean{istest}{true}}\fi }

\newcommand{\activate}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1>0 \setboolean{istest}{true}\fi}


%test boolean of true or false
\newcommand{\test}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{istest}}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%

\activate{10}
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

How can I use `true` or `false` as args.

```
\activate{true}
```

This has to set istest to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- Use `\setboolean{istest}{<true|false>}` directly
- or put it into a command (`\activate`)

**Note:** You could also use other ways (`bool` or `toggle`, see package manual of `etoolbox`).

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

%booleandeclaration
\newboolean{istest}
\setboolean{istest}{false}

\newcommand{\activate}[1]{%
    \setboolean{istest}{#1}
}


%test boolean of true or false
\newcommand{\test}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{istest}}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%

\begin{document}
\activate{true}
\test
\activate{false}
\test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do even better: the `\returnTorF` command accepts an argument in the forms

1. t, T, true, True, TRUE
2. y, Y, yes, Yes, YES
3. f, F, false, False, FALSE
4. n, N, no, No, NO
5. any integer

In cases 1 and 2, it returns `true`; in cases 3 and 4 it returns `false` (any capitalization, even TrUe is actually accepted); in case 5, `true` is returned if the integer is positive, `false` otherwise.

As an argument you can also use `\value{<counter>}`, which is a legal integer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}% but there are better methods

% we want to accept
%
% t, T, true, True, TRUE, y, yes, YES
%
% or
%
% f, F, false, False, FALSE, n, no, NO
%
% but also integers, with positive ones yielding true
% and nonpositive yielding false

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\returnTorF}{m}
 {
  \darkshadow_tf:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \darkshadow_tf:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \str_casefold:n { #1 } }
   {
    {t}{true}
    {y}{true}
    {true}{true}
    {yes}{true}
    {f}{false}
    {n}{false}
    {false}{false}
    {no}{false}
   }
   { \int_compare:nTF { #1 > 0 } { true } { false } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newboolean{istest}
\setboolean{istest}{false}

\newcommand{\activate}[1]{\setboolean{istest}{\returnTorF{#1}}}

\newcommand{\test}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{istest}}{TRUE}{FALSE}}

\begin{document}

\test\ (false)\par
\activate{y}
\test\ (true)\par
\activate{NO}
\test\ (false)\par
\activate{true}
\test\ (true)\par
\activate{0}
\test\ (false)\par
\activate{2}
\test\ (true)\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whether it is better to allow a variety of inputs that mean the same thing certainly depends on the use case. I can think offhand of 2 disadvantages compared to explicit input: Unnecessary conflicts in projects with multiple people if one boolean is changed in different ways each time. It complicates the search (needs regex) if you want to find where the boolean was set to true (or false).